# "Error 1064" when importing msql database after updating wordpress version to 4.2.1

Tags: mysql, collation

I have a error in importing my sql file that contains the db of my site
When i export from local, is ok
my settings

```
Server: mysql wampserver (127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP)
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.6.17 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Web server

```
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation
```

my OS is windows 7 and i have installed the above mysql on a Wamp server

The issue is when i import that file to my live website

I got the following error

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '5F????b>??),

('\0&F>????*!?^', 'wp-content/uploads/2013/05/IMG_82501-410x332' at line 6

I am getting nuts because both have same charset and collation! i dont get the issue
Until some days ago everything was fine, now i cannot update anymore my live db.

version of mysql live is 5.0, on a linux server. I have 1 gb of space.
the version were different also before but it worked fine so far. Only from 3 days ago it started this issue..,when was released and i installed the new Worpdress version. WordPress 4.2.1  (in both sites, live and local).

IF anyone could help, i would appreciate:)
thanks
paolo

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It has happened to me a couple of times. This is what helped me.

1. if you are uploading the .sql file which is compressed, try to import uncompressed .sql file.
2. Try to export the .sql database again, this error also comes when the database wasn't exported properly.

Comment: Hi, I tried to export a lot of times and is not compressed. I am using the "drop" table option when export. the only thing i can do is not using that. but everything is fine  and i dont find a proper reason